# Compact subsets of a space with discrete topology?

Tags: general-topology

Let X be a topological space with the discrete topology. What subsets of X are compact?

Comment: Think about finiteness.

Answer (score 2):

Since every singleton $\{x\}$ is open, then which subsets have the property that all open covers have finite subcovers?